# rails - grouped_collection_select with 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

The Rails docs example for grouped_collection_select is set up similar to what I need but I want to use 2 selects.  The first one will list the continents.  Then, based on the continent selection, I want to show a list of cities.

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :countries
  # attribs: id, name
end
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :continent
  # attribs: id, name, continent_id
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  # attribs: id, name, country_id
end
```

I know the first select would be written as:

```
<%= f.collection_select :continent_id, Continent.order(:name), :id, :name %>
```

The second one is giving me problems:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :city_id, Continent.order(:name), :countries, :name, :id, :name %>
```

The need for the country table is throwing me off.  Any suggestions?